# How to add firebase security rules for Flutter collection that hasn't been created yet

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase Auth and Firestore Database.  I'm trying to add security rules to Firebase Database that allow users to read, update, create and delete posts.  When I test my rules in the Rules Playground access is denied so I know that I have not written the rules correctly.  This is an image of the database prior to adding security rules.

[image]

Now that I have added the security rules the posts collection isn't created and I get error messages in the Rules Playground of:

```
> Simulated write denied 
> Simulated read denied
```

[image]

[image]

And I get console error of:

> The following _CastError was thrown building CommunityPage(dirty,
> dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>], state:
> _CommunityPageState#f5d54): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

In the app all users should be able to create posts to add to their profile.  When a user has a newly created account they do not have any posts that exist yet so I am trying to figure out how to include security rules that allow the page where posts will be displayed to appear even though it doesn't have any content when a new user is created.  I have reviewed SO threads and Firebase documentation but since I am new to Flutter and Firebase I can't figure things out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Since you say the problem occurs in the Rules Playground, can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the playground showing as many of the relevant values as possible?

Comment: I will edit my question. Thanks Puf!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see in the Rules Playground that:

- The `read` and `write` rules that are denied use the `isSignedIn()` function which checks if the `request.auth` object is not `null`;
- But you don't simulate the user's authentication while using the Rules Playground: see the "Authenticated" switch above the "Run" button in the left pane of the Rules Playground

You should activate the authentication simulation in the Rules Playground for your `isSignedIn()` function to be evaluated to `true`.

Note that most probably the error shown in the right part of the Playground shows a message corresponding to this problem but we don't see it in your screenshot.

---

**Update following your comment:**

Note that `request.resource` shall only be used in a `write` rule (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)): this probably explains the problem with the `read` rule (screenshot at the bottom in your question). You have to do:

```
allow read: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
```

Note that the above rules means that there is a field named `uid` in the `post` document.

For the `create` rule error: are you sure you pass the user's uid as the value of the field named `uid` in the newly created document?

Comment: Excellent point @RenaudTarnec. I have updated the images to show the Rules Playground message with Authentication turned on and I expanded the screen as far it it would go. That was an oversight on my part when I updated the images. I expanded the right side as much as possible.  At the very bottom right it was cut off but also said isSignedIN() true. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can now see where my mistakes are and what I need to do.  The uid is null so it makes sense.  You have pointed me in the right direction so I am confident I can fix the issue when I have time later to code.  Thank you very much.